# Yosemite Finder spins endlessly when browsing NFS mounted folders

Tags: macos, finder, mount

I have an NFS export on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I can mount it just fine from the command line in Yosemite:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw server:/home/gbell2/iOS_apps /Users/Devel/iOS_apps
```

And immediately I can `ls` it.  No problem.

Problem is, when I go into Finder and browse it, the little gray wheel at the bottom spins forever.

[image]

I cannot browse or open files in that folder from Xcode either.

I do not have [icon preview enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37543/finder-becomes-unresponsive-when-viewing-network-folders-with-large-amounts-of-f).
My [automount config](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102092/mount-linux-nfs-share-on-mountain-lion-10-8-5) just has Apple-generated stuff in it and while I know what automount is, these answers seem confused.

Another [answer fingering automount](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76037/browsing-in-finder-is-extremely-slow-while-fine-in-terminal) isn't really clear either.

I've tried the mount options like `rw,bg,hard,intr,noac,nfc,tcp` with no change in behavior.

There aren't a large amount of files in the root folder of that share.

I'm not mounting in /Volumes because one of the above references indicates that doesn't work any more.

Mounting with SMB doesn't have this issue, though I'd like to avoid the permissions issues that I usually see when tying *nix systems together with SMB.

Any ideas or how to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my... turns out it was one of the .* files in the share.  A simple rm of them all (excluding .git and/or .svn) and I was golden.

What a pain.  Hours gone.  I was unable to narrow down which file it was - a binary search failed so it may have been more than one.

Here's hoping lots of other people can be saved the time wastage.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and adding `locallocks` to the mount options fixed it for me.

(Alternatively, adding `nfsvers=4` fixed it as well, but I ended up getting kernel panics on the Mac client, so I went back to the default NFSv3.)